# Woocommerce Attribute price for non-variations

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I’m searching for an option to add non-variation attributes markup prices to the product regular price or to the variation’s price.

For example,

I have a product with a reg. price 120 and the attribute "Wood thickness" with terms: 1(+10 to regular price), 2(+15), 3(+20).
So if I add this attribute to the product (non-variation) and set it to 2 the regular price becomes 120+15=135.
And if I'll change "Wood thickness" term prices all products with this attribute change their prices too.

I wonder maybe someone uses any plugin or customization like that?

Comment: You want Product Add-Ons: https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/

Comment: Product Add-ons is good but you need to set prices individual for each product. I'm looking for how to add global attribute prices which can be used as passive(non-variation) markup to regular price.

Comment: There are global add-ons...

Comment: Thanks! Can I make a filter based on add-ons?